# How to do the Google search operator in a specific date range?

Tags: google-search

To set the search result only in a date range, I can add the search operators with the keyword:

```
stackoverflow daterange:2016-01-01..2016-12-31
```

or

```
stackoverflow daterange:2457389-2457735
```

[image: Search engine results]

However, results in 2017 still appear.

How can I get the search results to limit to the date range?